# tomcat cannot connect to https site : SNI error

Tags: java, tomcat, sni

I have tomcat application running on Ubuntu. When it tries to make a https call to google recaptcha site, I get a error  "No SNI provided, please fix client".  The same code works fine outside tomcat when I run as a standalone application using same Java.  Any ideas how to fix this.
URL app is trying to connect : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

Details :

```
Java version : openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
Tomcat Details :
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
Server built:   Jul 16 2020 22:38:29 UTC
Server number:  8.5.57.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.15.0-1028-aws
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_352-8u352-ga-1~20.04-b08
JVM Vendor:     Private Build
```

Java code :

```
public String webRequest(String url) {
    try {
        
        InputStream res = new URL(url).openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        res.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|19|http-nio-8080-exec-8|2023-01-24 23:19:20.155 UTC|CertificateMessage.java:366|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 90 76 89 18 E9 33 93 A0",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=invalid2.invalid, OU="No SNI provided; please fix your client."",
    "not before"         : "2015-01-01 24:00:00.000 UTC",
    "not  after"         : "2030-01-01 24:00:00.000 UTC",
    "subject"            : "CN=invalid2.invalid, OU="No SNI provided; please fix your client."",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
```

Comment: You present tomcat's log output. What is the exception thrown in the code? The one that your catch block silently swallows.

Comment: **UTC|TransportContext.java:316|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:456)

Comment: In the catch block , I did a printStackTrace and got the above error.  The same sample program , if I run outside tomcat , works.  But ifI put that inside the tomcat and called from a JSP its fails.  It may have to do with tomcat lib or tomcat configuration .

Comment: Check to see if `System.getProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension")` has a value other than null or "true". That's the only thing I can see that should cause 8u352 to omit SNI for HttpsURLConnection with a valid domain name, although I can't see any good reason why a Tomcat environment would set it.

Comment: I passed value for jsse.enableSNIExtension as false as -D param , still no luck.

Comment: On some other forums they say it might be related to the self-signed certificate. Try adding it to the _System Truststore_.